# input type="number" not aligned with input="checkbox" when in flexbox

Tags: html, css

Currently, the input="number" is in the top right hand corner of the flexbox. When I change it from input="number" to input="checkbox" it becomes aligned. How do I make it so that when  it is input="number" it aligns with the rest of the checkboxes?

```css
body {
  background-color : #6d6875;
  font-family      : 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  }
#options-div {
  background-color : #b5838d;
  margin           : 200px auto;
  padding          : 20px;
  width            : 350px;
  text-align       : center;
  border           : 2px solid white;
  }
#password-output {
  width  : 200px;
  }
#num-box {
  width  : 30px;
  height : 30px;
  }
.options {
  display         : flex;
  justify-content : space-between;
  border          : 2px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<div id="options-div">
  <h1>Password generator</h1>
  <input id="password-output" type="number">
  <div class="options">
    <p>Password length</p>
    <input id="num-box" type="number">
  </div>
  <div class="options">
    <p>Include uppercase letters</p>
    <input type="checkbox">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you should use a css reset; normalize.css for example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.options {
  display         : flex;
  justify-content : space-between;
  border          : 2px solid black;
  align-items     : center;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

With this, the input box for each choice will be positioned to the right of the text. By changing the width of the elements or adding padding or margin, you can change the distance between the text and the input box.

```
#options-div {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center; /* This line is optional and can be used to 
 vertically center the items */
 border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color : #6d6875;
  font-family      : 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  }
#options-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center; /* This line is optional and can be used to 
  vertically center the items */
  border: 2px solid black;
  }
#password-output {
  width  : 200px;
  }
#num-box {
  width  : 30px;
  height : 30px;
  }
.options {
  display         : flex;
  justify-content : space-between;
  border          : 2px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<div id="options-div">
  <h1>Password generator</h1>
  <input id="password-output" type="number">
  <div class="options">
    <p>Password length</p>
    <input id="num-box" type="number">
  </div>
  <div class="options">
    <p>Include uppercase letters</p>
    <input type="checkbox">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it:
Change the `<p>` for `<label>` and add with your `display: flex` the `justify-content: space-between` and the `align-items: center`.

In this case, the align-items will align the content in the `center` of your line.

```css
body {
  background-color : #6d6875;
  font-family      : 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
#options-div {
  background-color : #b5838d;
  margin           : 200px auto;
  padding          : 20px;
  width            : 350px;
  text-align       : center;
  border           : 2px solid white;
}
#password-output {
  width  : 200px;
}
#num-box {
  width  : 30px;
  height : 30px;
}
.options {
  width           : 100%;
  min-height      : 30px;
  display         : flex;
  align-items     : center;
  justify-content : space-between;
  border          : 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="options-div">
  <h1>Password generator</h1>
  <input id="password-output" type="number">
  <div class="options">
    <label>Password length</label>
    <input id="num-box" type="number">
  </div>
  <div class="options">
    <label>Include uppercase letters</label>
    <input type="checkbox">
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope I've helped!